# Is it possible to use "Styled Maps" with MKMapView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, google-maps, mapkit

Cheers,

for about a year now Google allows you to adjust the styling of their maps according to your needs. They offer a tool which allows for the easy creation of styles too:

[Google Maps API Styled Maps Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html)

What I'd like to know is: can this feature of their API be used with MKMapView as provided in the Map Kit Framework? If so, how and at which point would I feed the JSON code which the wizard produces to the API?

If this doesn't work with MKMapView: What's the next best way to include Googles Styled Maps in an app?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, `MKMapView` doesn't provide this functionality "out of the box" as the Google Maps API does; the [class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html), seems to support this hypothesis. You could re-implement some of the styles using annotations and overlays (see the class reference), but that assumes you have access to the point of interest data. Your success will likely depend on what styles you want to use.

As for the next best way, I opened your link, the styled maps wizard, on my iPad and it seems to work flawlessly. Perhaps you could host a pre-styled map somewhere online and simply show it in your app using a `UIWebView`? That would obviously limit you in some ways, but at least it would be styled!

Comment: If taking this UIWebView approach, you should just save a html string and load it into webview using -loadHTMLString:baseURL: method to take the load off your server.

Comment: Any idea if now that Apple is taking maps into their own hands styling options will be added? I'd like to do a map heavy app but doing so severely limits design.